# Load test under linux (memory, total time, %cpu)

Tags: java, shell, testing, pid

I have to perform a load test under Red Hat Linux 6.2 using standard software, i.e. I cannot install anything there. It is intended to take account of total time, total memory use and % of cpu for 1000 10000 100000 and 1000000 iterations.

The software I have to test consists in a producer and a consumer. Both are started as independent processes.
My idea was to use the **top** linux command in batch mode.

I wrote two bash scripts for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 of repetitions

echo $$
java -jar jms-test-tool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -S -N$1 -F./IN -Ddummy > ./input.log

java -jar jms-test-tool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -C -N$1 -F./OUT -Ddummy > ./output.log
```

The very first thing this script does is to send to standard output his own **pid** (echo $$).
This scripts receives as parameter the number of iteratins ($1) which is used as a parameter  for the java process (-N$1). The first java call will send a file $1 times to the second process and the second process will read $1 times files.

The second script (master.sh) has a for loop with the required steps (1000 10000 100000 and 1000000) calling in every iteration the slave and receiving the **pid** of the slave.

```
master.sh
#!/bin/bash
for steps in 1000 10000 100000 1000000
do
  pid=`./slave.sh $steps `

  echo "Slave pid is : $pid"
  top -b -p$pid      
done
```

Using **top** I wanted to get the memory, time and %cpu used, but the **pid** of the slave doesn't appear at the process table.

Then two questions. What am I doing wrong here?
Anybody knows a better way for performing this test?

Comment: FYI: Here's a good guide to [linux monitoring tools](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html)

Comment: The shell has to wait until the process in the backticks finishes. When it gets to calling `top`, it's long gone - that's why it's not there anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "pid=`prog`" will give you the output of prog in pid only after prog has completed.

You want to do something like "prog & pid=$!" to get the pid of the process launched into the background.  You can then do anything you like to analyze this process, and if you want to pause until the process terminates, use "wait $pid".